# Using gfortran on win10 with Matlab 2017b

Tags: matlab, gfortran, mex

I'd like to compile fortran code in Matlab 2017b, Win10, to get a mex-file. Does anyone know how to bypass the limitation of matlab in selecting Intel's compiler and force it to use gfortran instead?

I have a simple example fortran code, "timestwo.f".

```
#include "fintrf.h"
C======================================================================
#if 0
C     
C     timestwo.F
C     .F file needs to be preprocessed to generate .for equivalent
C     
#endif
C     
C     timestwo.f
C
C     Computational function that takes a scalar and doubles it.
      
C     This is a MEX-file for MATLAB.
C     Copyright 1984-2011 The MathWorks, Inc.
C     
C======================================================================
C     Gateway routine
      subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
      implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
      mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
      integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
      mwPointer mxGetPr
      mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
      integer mxIsNumeric
      mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
      mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr

C     Array information:
      mwPointer mrows, ncols
      mwSize size

C     Arguments for computational routine:
      real*8  x_input, y_output

C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
      if(nrhs .ne. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:nInput',
     +                           'One input required.')
      elseif(nlhs .gt. 1) then
         call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:nOutput',
     +                           'Too many output arguments.')
      endif

C     Validate inputs
C     Check that the input is a number.
      if(mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .eq. 0) then
         call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:NonNumeric',
     +                           'Input must be a number.')
      endif

C     Get the size of the input array.
      mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
      ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
      size = mrows*ncols

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
      x_ptr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
      call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x_input,size)

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
      plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols,0)
      y_ptr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

C     Call the computational subroutine.
      call timestwo(y_output, x_input)

C     Load the data into y_ptr, which is the output to MATLAB.
      call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_output,y_ptr,size)     

      return
      end

C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Computational routine

      subroutine timestwo(y_output, x_input)
      real*8 x_input, y_output

      y_output = 2.0 * x_input
      return
      end
```

Officially this Matlab release in windows only supports Intel's commercial Fortran compiler ifor. Is there any work-around for this? I initially installed MinGW as  official add-on of matlab, but I noticed that this specifically release does not contain gfortran.

Therefore I manually installed the same version (but with gfortran) and changed the environment variables accordingly.

Mex generation of C code works smoothly, but when I tried to select g-fortran I get this

```
>> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB
     variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. You will be required
     to update your code to utilize the new API.
     You can find more information about this at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.

To choose a different language, select one from the following:
 mex -setup C++ 
 mex -setup FORTRAN
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.
```

and, consequently, when I try to compile the function it only looks for Intel's compiler.

```
>> mex -v timestwo.F
Verbose mode is on.
Warning: MATLAB FORTRAN MEX Files are now defaulting to -largeArrayDims and 8 byte integers.
     If you are building a FORTRAN S-Function, please recompile using the -compatibleArrayDims flag.
     You can find more about adapting code to use 64-bit array dimensions at:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html. 
No MEX options file identified; looking for an implicit selection.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER14' ...No.
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER13' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER15' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER15' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER15' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER16' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER16' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER16' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER17' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft SDK 7.1'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER17' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER17' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'.
... Looking for compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'IFORT_COMPILER17' ...No.
Did not find installed compiler 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017'.
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. For options, visit https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.
```

Did anyone manage to use gfortran instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ifort is free to download for non-commercial purposes, and arguably is more performant than gfortran.

Comment: Hi @Lingo, where do you see that Ifort is free to download for non-commercial purposes? Matlab only looks for Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE releases.

Comment: Hi I remember having downloaded and used it successfully a few years ago. Try to start from here https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/oneapi-standalone-components.html#fortran pick your poison, it will probably ask you to fill some kind of registration and then allow the download.

Comment: @Lingo thanks, I'm having a look to see whtether I find the old version required for my matlab version, even though I still hope there is a work-around to get it working with gfortran.

Comment: It would be unusual for the up-to-date version of Ifort to have incompatibilities. Probably all these XE packages can be found included in Ifort classic.

Comment: @Lingo just got the Intel fortran compiler. I'll give a try.

Comment: MATLAB has some supported compilers. If you chose to use a non-supported one, then it won't compile, as such is the definition of a compiler being supported. Just use the one that MATLAB allows!

Comment: @Ander Biguri, thanks but this is not what I asked. I know it is possible to do so. Being not supported means it might now work, which I know it is not the case. Thanks though.

Comment: You are correct. but this might be the case when it does not work.

Comment: Just a note, Intel oneAPI is now available for free (as in beer) for commercial purposes as well.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава do you know if Matlab releases prior to the addition of explicit oneAPI support (I think R2021b or R2022a) will recognize the Intel Fortran compiler from oneAPI?

Comment: I do not but I do not see why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use an old project [Gnumex](http://gnumex.sourceforge.net/) which "Compile matlab mex files with gcc on Windows Platforms" as they described. However, gfortran can only work perfectly for 32-bit and there are some problems for 64-bit.

The problem comes from MATLAB. When MATLAB uses a compiler it calls a lot of libraries which are stored at `${MATLABroot}\extern\lib\win64` and it **only provides .lib library for windows version**. Mingw can link successfully to .lib library under 32-bit but not 64-bit. Another suitable way to handle this problem is that you can use `reimp` to convert all the .lib library to .a. Then modify the setup file `C:\Users\${Yourname}\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\${MATLABversion}\mex_FORTRAN_win64.xml` and `${MATLABroot}\bin\win64\mexopts\intel_fortran_*_vs*.xml` to force the MATLAB to use gfortran and link to .a library.